# How to call a request body method from a spring mvc Requestmapping method that returns string

Tags: android, json, rest, spring-mvc

I have a controller class with method named Loginsuccesspage. This method is used to download a file and insert some of the user details into the Database. And in-turn it returns to the loginsuccess page it self (which is a JSP). Now am trying to refactor the code in such a way that it needs to download and return to JSP Loginsuccess page and also should construct the user details in a JSON format in a specified URL (machineip:portno/target). This URL will be accessed from my android application for retrieving user details. I am attaching the LoginsuccessPage method which does the Download logic & getUserDetails method which returns JSON object. This approach is not working. Is there any other way we can implement this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginsuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginSuccessPage(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


    if (username != null) {

        model.addAttribute("message1", username);


    } else {
        model.addAttribute("message1", deleteUserName);
    }
    HashMap<String, String> appList = new HashMap<String, String>();

    List list = this.loginService.findAppPrice();


    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Price price = (Price) list.get(i);
        appList.put(price.getApp_name(), price.getApp_price().toString());
    }
    model.addAttribute("appList", appList);

    try {

        if (filename != null) {

            String appName=filename.substring(0,filename.length()-4);
            Double price = appstoreBillingService.appStoreBilling(appName);
            Appstorebilling appstorebilling = new Appstorebilling();
            appstorebilling.setUname(username);
            appstorebilling.setApp_name(appName);
            appstorebilling.setApp_price(price);
            appstorebilling.setTime_stamp(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            String downloadSize = this.paymentService.downloadFile(request, response, filename);
            appstorebilling.setDownload_size(downloadSize);
            appstoreBillingService.insertBillingInfo(appstorebilling);
            getUserDetails(appstorebilling); //Method which i am invoking to GET JSON object 

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "loginsuccess";

}
```

Method which i am invoking to GET JSON object

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/target",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object getUserDetails(Appstorebilling appstorebilling) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

     return appstorebilling;

}
```

When i try to access url  (machineip:portno/target) I am getting null values in the JSON object
{"id":0,"uname":null,"app_name":null,"app_price":null,"time_stamp":null,"download_size":null}

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding your question or you have impossible expectations. You call `getUserDetails(appstorebilling);` from your `loginSuccessPage` method. That immediately returns the object you passed as an argument. Do you expect another HTTP request that will be handled by invoking the `getUserDetails()` method to return that same object?

Comment: The method loginSuccessPage is nothing but a download logic where when user clicks a specific file attached to that page gets downloaded and it returns to the loginsuccess.jsp page itself from where we downloaded the files. The method getUserDetails is to just return the Userdetails when this download action took place. user details namely uname, download time, download file name etc. like for eg {"id":0,"uname":null,"app_name":null,"app_price":null,"time_stamp":null,"download_size":null}.  actually in this i just get null instead of values for each arguments.

Comment: My requirement is two things. One is when i click download file it should perform file download by returning to the same page (loginsuccess.jsp -- which works fine now) and post JSON object of User details to a specific URL (machineip:portno/target    ---- in my case) which is not working.

Comment: Am still not sure whether i need to have getUserDetails method to return JSON object or this can be handled in loginSuccessPage method itself along with file download option. If so how. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Let me reformulate: Why do you expect a GET request to `machineip:portno/target` to return anything other than what you are currently seeing?

Comment: I need this User details to be sent to my android application using REST. Thats the logic which i am working on. So i am trying to GET or POST JSON object (not sure which one will work) to http://localhost:8080/target

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: My previous comment gives the reason for the expectations for GET or POST request. Not sure whether i am making it clear to you.

Comment: No. You are stating what you need, what the logic you want is. I want you to tell me why you think that sending a GET request to `machineip:portno/target` that will be handled by the `getUserDetails()` method you've shown would return a JSON with anything other than `null` values.

Comment: You state `When i try to access url (machineip:portno/target) I am getting null values in the JSON object {"id":0,"uname":null,"app_name":null,"app_price":null,"time_stamp":null,"download_size":null}`. Why do you think that happens?

Comment: Now i got your question. we are invoking getUserDetails method from loginsuccesspage method where we are passing appstorebilling object. So when we invoke /target url separately the object will obviously return null. Not sure how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Samba, try to change your logic little bit.

**Server setup**

> Assumption: F = the file you want to download, J = the JSON file having information of the file.

1. Have the two controllers (or places) one is returning J, and the other returning F by client request with parameters.
2. Put the location information of the F in J.

**Client procedure**

1. Get J first.
2. Grab the location information of F from J, and call the location of F to download the F.

Let me know if there is any problem of implementation.

Comment: Thanks Sky. I will try this logic and get back to you.